# Creating a Sandbox Compatible WebPart that extends Rss webpart functionality?

Tags: web-part, sandbox-solution

I'm trying to create a web part that can pull in twitter feeds on a sandbox site. Since sandbox webparts cannot make cross domain calls, I thought that I could use an old trick I enjoyed, which was pulling in the RSS feed of a twitter account.

I'd like to have a nice interface where someone just adds the account name as a property, and it pulls the feed in.

Can I create what essentially amounts to a custom skin for an out of the box web part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you don't need to override the out of box RSS webpart. (you can't anyways override the rss webpart in sandbox)

I have implemented this functionality previously using http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/

It's a simple jQuery plugin which accepts a twitter username (and many other properties) and displays the public twitter feeds from that account.

What you could do is, use this plugin in your Custom WebPart and then:

1) Accept the username as a web part property
2) Using that username build the plugin javascript serverside.
3) Push the javascript containing the username and the plugin code to the page.

Comment: Upvote for coolness! Does this rely on a cross domain proxy like Yahoo's? A lot of internal corporate networks will block that sort of thing.

Comment: I don't think it relies on cross domain proxys. It directly calls the Public Twitter search API. You can see the entire code over here:
https://github.com/seaofclouds/tweet/blob/master/tweet/jquery.tweet.js